# Using clob instead of multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I am a newbie when it comes with the effect of Database design on performance. I am creating an app which uses hibernate to query the DB. I am trying to create a DB schema for the application and I'm confused between using clobs and separate tables for some of the data. I have the following tables:

```
Person(id, name)
Address(person_id,address(varchar2))
products_bought(person_id, product_name(varchar2))
places_visited(person_id, place_name(varchar2))
..few more tables
```

I am sure I need to write/read the data to/from all these table every time. I'm thinking of designing them this way to reduce the tables thereby reducing the number of joins I need to make and make it easy for hibernate to fetch the info in one-go:

```
Person(id, name, products_bought(CLOB), places_visited(CLOB))
Address(person_id,address(varchar2))
..few more tables
```

Now I came across many posts online arguing that the performance will take a hit when using CLOBs. Same goes when using JOINs. How do I decide which is better based on the fact that the person table will not have more than 10K rows?

Comment: This is a very bad idea for so many reasons I don't even know where to start. In short, don't do this. Your joins will be fine.

Comment: @mustaccio, Thanks. I have to join 9 tables at one go which lead me to think about CLOBs for some of the 'Person' attributes.

Comment: Bad, Bad, Bad!!

Comment: Joins are something that the Oracle database is very very good at. Its been doing them for many many years. Think about your alternative; how would you query a specific product? What is the product name for a specific product changed...?

Comment: @BobC, Pls dont pay much attention to the attribute details. I just came up with dummy attributes as I didnt want to give the actual entire model.